# How to bold day for multiple hour tables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, html-table

I currently have this code which highlights the day for an hours table that I have. It does this job properly for the one table, but not for the others. I have 4 tables in total on this page and need it to bold the day for each of them.

```
<script>
        var days = 'sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday'.split(',');
        document.getElementById( days[(new Date()).getDay()] ).className = 'pw-bold';
</script>
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="pw-table-header">Hours</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pw-table">
                <div id="sunday">Sunday</div>
            </td>
            <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pw-table">
                <div id="monday">Monday</div>
            </td>
            <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pw-table">
                <div id="tuesday">Tuesday</div>
            </td>
            <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pw-table">
                <div id="wednesday">Wednesday</div>
            </td>
            <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pw-table">
                <div id="thursday">Thursday</div>
            </td>
            <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pw-table">
                <div id="friday">Friday</div>
            </td>
            <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="pw-table">
                <div id="saturday">Saturday</div>
            </td>
            <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
.pw-bold{font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: hint: `getElementById` can only find one item, because `id` attributes _must_ be unique on a page. If you have multiple elements with the same `id`, the first one is considered "the real one" and the rest get completely ignored for any DOM purposes. If you need "multiple elements with the same thing to identify them on", you want a class, not an id.

Comment: Is there a getElement command which can be used for multiple elements? For instance, if I used getElementbyClass, would that work for each of them?

Comment: There is, it's [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: You want to change it from an ID into a class name  and use `document.querySelectorAll('.' + days[(new Date()).getDay()] )`. Then you can iterate over the array and set the `className`s. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Also, in modern JS, don't use `+` to compose strings through concatenation, which can have all kinds of hilarious bugs if one of the parts isn't a true string. Instead, use [templating strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which were added to the language years ago to prevent those bugs: ```const day = days[(new Date()).getDay()]; document.querySelectorAll(`.${day}`)```.

Comment: Another hint, stay away from IDs whenever you can, specially hard coded ones, unless you want them to be URL anchors bu I rarely need to reference IDs in my JS unless it's to create a generated ID to match a label and its form control if it's not inside the label.

Answer (score 1):

`id`s must be unique, which is probably the cause of the issue.

Try using a custom data `id` attribute or perhaps a class.

For example:

```js
var days = 'sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday'.split(',');
document.querySelectorAll('[data-id=' + days[(new Date()).getDay()]).forEach(e => e.className = 'pw-bold')
```

```css
.pw-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="pw-table-header">Hours</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="sunday">Sunday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="monday">Monday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="tuesday">Tuesday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="wednesday">Wednesday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="thursday">Thursday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="friday">Friday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="saturday">Saturday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>

<table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="pw-table-header">Hours</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="sunday">Sunday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="monday">Monday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="tuesday">Tuesday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="wednesday">Wednesday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="thursday">Thursday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="friday">Friday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="saturday">Saturday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>

<table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="pw-table-header">Hours</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="sunday">Sunday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="monday">Monday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="tuesday">Tuesday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="wednesday">Wednesday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="thursday">Thursday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="friday">Friday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="saturday">Saturday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>

<table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="pw-table-header">Hours</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="sunday">Sunday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="monday">Monday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="tuesday">Tuesday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="wednesday">Wednesday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="thursday">Thursday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="friday">Friday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">7:00am - 4:00pm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="pw-table">
        <div data-id="saturday">Saturday</div>
      </td>
      <td class="pw-table">Closed</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>
```

Comment: Or, you know, classes. No need for data attributes here.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I suppose it's a matter of taste. I may call it `data-day-name` to be more descriptive than just a class (or an id).

Comment: you probably want to replace those composed strings with the modern string syntax though. Using `+` is a giant source of coercion-related bugs, and hasn't been necessary for a few years now. Also, rather than assigning `.className`, using .`classList.add(...)` so you don't wipe any preexisting classes is generally much safer code.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans While true, it's good to keep the solution as close to the original as possible to help others understand that a diff is part of the solution, not some best practice that we should be using. I also think this is a matter of taste, I prefer backticks too but let's focus on the problem, this not really an egregious mistake. I suppose a paragraph explaining any additional improvements to the code should be explained as an aside. So yes, using classes probably would have been more inline with what I said before :p Yes, we really should not modify `className` directly...

Comment: Counter-point: templating strings are literally the opposite of personal taste: they were introduced to _prevent bugs_, specifically the kind that is far more common for beginners than people who already know their way around JS, because beginners are going to run into JS's coercion behaviour _far more_ than experienced programmers, making templating strings super important to teach early on as "only ever use these until you actually know when you don't need them, which will be almost never" =)